# Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

Tags: symfony

i want to add in my form a comboBox .

in my formType i have:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('dateDepart', 'date', array(
                                    'input'  => 'datetime',
                                    'widget' => 'choice',   
                                        ))
        ->add('dateRetour', 'date', array(
                                    'input'  => 'datetime',
                                    'widget' => 'choice',
                                        ))
    ->add('nbreJour')
    ->add('justificatif')
    ->add("email", "email", array("mapped"=>false))
    ->add("emailcdp", "email", array("mapped"=>false))
    ->add('public', 'choice', array(
        'choices'   => array(
            'matin'   => 'Matin',
            'apresmidi' => 'Après-midi',
            'soir'   => 'Soir',
        ),
        'multiple'  => true,
        "mapped"=>false
    ));


}
```

in twig i have this:

```
   <div>
    {{ form_errors(form.public) }}
    {{ form_label(form.public, 'type:') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.public) }}
</div>
 <div>
    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    {{ form_label(form.email, 'Email Collaborateur:') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.emailcdp) }}
    {{ form_label(form.emailcdp, 'Email Chef:') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.emailcdp) }}
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.nbreJour) }}
    {{ form_label(form.nbreJour, 'Nombre de jour') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.nbreJour) }}
</div>
 <div>
    {{ form_errors(form.justificatif) }}
    {{ form_label(form.justificatif, 'Justificatif:') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.justificatif) }}
 </div>
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.dateDepart) }}
    {{ form_label(form.dateDepart, 'Date depart:') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.dateDepart) }}
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.dateRetour) }}
    {{ form_label(form.dateRetour, 'Date retour') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.dateRetour) }}
</div>
```

the form worked very well but when i added 'choice' it give me exception:Twig_Error_Runtime
i don't know howa to use it i want to use a comboBox .

Comment: what is the message of Twig_error_runtime ?!

Comment: Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

Comment: and what is the exception ? should be after the sentence you posted

Comment: i have this Exception : Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

Comment: @user3816170 there is always another exception in such cases. Can you post a screen shot of you error page?

Comment: there should be a line reported in the error that will point you to the location of the problem in thew twig file.  You do have {{ form_start(form) }} and {{ form_end(form) }}?

Comment: i changed choice with entity now it's work well :

Comment: ->add('type_conge', 'entity', array(
       'class' => 'SqliGestionCongeBundle:TypeConge',
       'property' => 'type',
   ));